# Android ConstraintLayout: Views not respecting margins

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-constraintlayout

I am attempting to create a layout where various pieces of data are separated by a line (View), but the design requires an equal top and bottom spacing from the line.  I am trying to use margins to accomplish this, but I am not getting the results I expected.  Based on the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#Margins), as long as the constraints are set for the margin direction, they should be respected.  For some reason the top margin gives us the correct spacing, however the bottom margin does not give any spacing at all.  I have created a sample containing only the pertinent layout axml to reproduce, along with a large enough margin to visualize the issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp">
    <TextView android:text="NAME"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/account_name_label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />
    <TextView android:text="Your Name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/account_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/account_name_label"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/account_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/account_joined_label"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        />
    <TextView android:text="JOINED"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/account_joined_label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/line1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        />
    <TextView android:text="January 1, 2019"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/account_joined"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/account_joined_label"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The above results in the following, visually:
[image: ConstraintLayout margin issue]

Now, I can add the `android:layout_marginTop="100dp"` to the first TextView after the line View to "fix" this, however I want to reuse the styles for the line View, without having to worry about remembering to add a top margin to whatever happens to be the first View after the line View.  What am I missing?

**Update:** Here is what the layout SHOULD look like:

[image: ConstraintLayout corrected layout]

Comment: Do you have an image of how you want your layout to look like?

Comment: @TamirAbutbul I have added a snapshot of what I would expect the layout to look like.

Comment: Check my answer below  - hope this will help you with your problem.

Comment: Thanks for that - I have updated that to constrain to parent - this is a dumbed down version of my larger layout, and this was accidentally left in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to connect the bottom of `account_joined` to the bottom of parent and the bottom of `account_joined_label` to the top of `account_joined`. So you can try this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="20dp">

    <TextView android:text="NAME"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/account_name_label"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView android:text="Your Name"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/account_name"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/account_name_label"
              app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/account_name"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/account_joined_label"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"/>

    <TextView android:text="JOINED"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/account_joined_label"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/line1"
              app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/account_joined" />

    <TextView android:text="January 1, 2019"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/account_joined"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/account_joined_label"
              app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.  Apparently you need to complete the top to bottom chain for everything to work as expected.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Some info before the code:**

When you use something like `android:layout_marginTop="100dp"` you are making your layout to a non-responsive one.

**Why:** In android, different phones got dofferent screen size and what may look good on 1 device with 100dp margin may not look good on another device.

So if possible try not to use large values as fixed sizes, the next part of the question will explain how to handle this.

---

**Here is where the fun begins:**

You can simply use [Guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) to fix your margin problems - it will be responsive to all screen sizes and won't have hardcoded value like `120dp`.

All you have to do is to constraint "NAME" to the top constraint and "JOINED" to the bottom constraint like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/account_name_label"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="NAME"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline9" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/account_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Your Name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/account_name_label" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/line1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/account_joined_label"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/account_name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/account_joined_label"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="JOINED"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/account_joined"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="January 1, 2019"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/account_joined_label"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.85" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.15" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**And it will look like this:**

[image]

Now don't be scared, your layout looks ok - it's just my lame lame skills in editing photos (check this on your device).

The important thing is that you can  change the look of your layout by changing the value of this line in your guidelines:

```
 app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.15"
```

If anything was not understandable feel free to ask.

Comment: While this didn't answer the question directly, it definitely has value as an alternative to margins.  Thank you for that.

Comment: Hey, there is a reason I did not answer with something like 100dp as margin. Just edited my answer - feel free to check it and see if this will help you.

Comment: Oh I get it.  I was only using 100dp for this example to show the obvious margin working on the top, but not the bottom.  The actual margin value for the design is 16dp.